# common lisp symbol matching

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have an alist in the following form:

```
((|* bank accounts| (|account 1| |account 2|))
 (|* airline miles| (|account 1| |account 2|))
 .....
 .....)
```

I don't how to use `assoc` to access the symbols, since they're framed on both sides with "|".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoted symbols are treated like any other symbol, but the string case of the symbol is preserved:

`(assoc '|foo bar| '((|baz| . 1) (|foo bar| . 2))) => (|foo bar| . 2)`

Here are some more examples (with standard reader case settings):

`(intern "foo bar") => |foo bar|`

`(intern "Foo") => |Foo|`

`(intern "FOO") => FOO`

A longer answer can be found [on cliki](http://www.cliki.net/Case%20sensitivity).  Please also refer to [2.3.4 Symbols as Tokens](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/02_cd.htm) in the [Common Lisp Hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Front/index.htm).

Comment: it was the case that got me... using (string-upcase) on all the elements when compiling the alist solved it.

Answer (score 3):

The same way they are printed:

```
> (defparameter *alist* 
                '((|* bank accounts| |account 1| |account 2|)
                  (|* airline miles| |account 1| |account 2|)))
*ALIST*
> (cdr (assoc '|* bank accounts| *alist*))  
(|account 1| |account 2|)
> (cdr (assoc '|* airline miles| *alist*))                                             
(|account 1| |account 2|)
```

The vertical-bars are just multiple escape characters allowing the use of characters which the standard reader wouldn't read as a symbol. For example, whitespace would result in separate symbols in standard reader syntax:

```
> (read-from-string "foo bar")
FOO ;
4
```

Numbers won't yield a symbol:

```
> (read-from-string "123 456")
123 ;
4
> (type-of *)
(INTEGER 0 16777215)
```

Without escaping, and the default readtable-case, the read symbols would be in upper case:

```
> 'foo
FOO
```

But:

```
> (intern "1234")
|1234| ;
NIL
> (type-of *)
SYMBOL
> '|foo bar baz|
|foo bar baz|
> (symbol-name *)
"foo bar baz"
```